# Share count endpoints for Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest

Tags: facebook, twitter, share, counter, pinterest

I've noticed that share count endpoints for Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest are not being updated in realtime.

Twitter caches count and updates from time to time. It also doesn't include tweets from protected accounts.

What are known issues/details on how often share count endpoints of these three networks are being updated? Are private Facebook shares being counted? What about pins on Pinterest's secret boards?